# Displaying an image created with imagecreatefromstring

Tags: php, html, image, gd, jpeg

Let's say I have the code that looks something like:

```
<?PHP

//
//... stuff here
//

$im = imagecreatefromstring( $imageData );

echo "<img src=" . /* what goes here? */ . "alt=\"the image\" />";


//
// more stuff here
//
?>
```

What do I replace /* what goes here? */ with so my image data will display?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What do I replace /* what goes here? */ with so my image data will display?

The location you highlighted is the so called `src` attribute of the [`img` HTML-tag<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/element/img). The value is a so called [URI<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-uri).

In your case you want that URI to point to the image data in question. You have not specified which type the image should be output as, so I will assume it's a PNG image in the following example.

You now need to convert your image data into an URI. The most straight forward URI to create from the image data is a so called [`data:` URI<sup>*Wikipedia*</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

```
<?PHP

//
//... stuff here
//

$im = imagecreatefromstring( $imageData );

ob_start();
imagepng($img);
$png = ob_get_clean();
$uri = "data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($png);

echo "<img src=" . $uri /* URI goes here */ . " alt=\"the image\" />";

//
// more stuff here
//
?>
```

Even this is the most straight forward way, it is not always recommended to do so because the image data will be returned with the HTML to the browser. If the image is large, this is commonly considered an overhead.

Instead of using the `data:` URI you can place any other URI in there as well, for example a HTTP URI that is pointing to a PHP script on your server that is returning the image. Such a script can be very simple:

```
<?php
$img = imagecreatefromstring($string);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
```

This is comparable to what [Marc B suggested, see his answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961097/displaying-an-image-created-with-imagecreatefromstring/6961213#6961213).

Comment: Thank you! Output buffering was what I needed to do; wish I could give you a +5!

Comment: Didn't work for me until I added a space before ` alt=`...   also, perhaps for OCD reasons, I added added quotes around the raw image data.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$img = imagecreatefromstring($string);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($img);
```

should be all you need. Doing it with the image tag as you are, you'd need to output the image to a temporary file and point the image tag at that (which incurs a second HTTP request), or use a [data url](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the resource to a file first or output it using something like [`imagepng()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) in a separate request.

See [`imagecreatefromstring()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) documentation for more information.

If you want to use a [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), you can try this instead:

```
<?php

// If your image is binary data. use `base64_encode($imageData)`.
$imageData = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
           . 'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
           . 'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
           . '8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';

echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'. $imageData .'" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this...

```
$src = "data:image/gif;base64," . $imageData ;
echo "<img src=\"$src\" alt=\"the image\" />";
```