# Limit display of Facebook avatars to either a random number or the first 196

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here is a snippet of my code

```
<?php
$me = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
foreach( $me['data'] as $frns ) {
?>
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/"<?php echo $frns['id'] ?>"/picture" 
      title="<?php echo $frns['name'] ?>"/>
<?php
}
```

I want to merge all of the images using something like

```
$im = mergeImages( array( image1, image2, etc ) );
```

How can I limit the merge to only the first 196 or a random number of images?

Comment: I'm not at all sure what it is you're actually asking here.

Comment: ok . let me explain . in this script . i have over 1600 friends . so when i run this script . i got my all friends profile pic in one page . but i want reduce it too only 100 friends only .

Comment: consider array_slice($friends_array, 0, 160, true) to keep only 160...

Comment: Argh. I accidentally left two quotes on the `img` tag's src attribute. I can't edit it because of the 6 char restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this. You won't have to make another series of API calls to get the urls for the pictures, and your script won't have to deal with the 301 redirects Facebook typically throws for an image.

```
$me = $facebook->api('/me/friends?fields=name,picture');
echo "<br />Total friends".sizeof($me['data'])."<br />";

echo "<br /> Friends collage<br /><br />";

$frns_images = array();
$i = 1;
foreach($me['data'] as $frns)
{
   if ($i >= 100) break;
   $img = $frns['picture']['data']['url']; //Double check this.
   if ('jpg' === substr($img, -3)) {
     printf ('<img  src="%s" title="%s" />', $img, $frns['name']);
     $frns_images[] = $img;
     $i++;
   }
}
$im = mergeImages($frns_images);
```

Comment: Thank you for your Ans . but some people have profile pic in .gif . so it is give error like this 

`Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: 'http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v2/yo/r/UlIqmHJn-SK.gif' is not a valid JPEG file in /home/repackg1/public_html/crazy4tech.in/fb/index.php on line 122`.

so . please i want only profile pic in JPG . and also i want only 100 profile pic .

Comment: This is My App source code . please see this 

http://tny.cz/417d9262

and i want to use this script in this APP

http://snipplr.com/view/13146/

Comment: Edited my answer. Alternatively you could accept all image types by changing line 54 of the snipplr code to `$tmp = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents($images[$i]) );`

Comment: this is final source code but it is not working . 

http://tny.cz/dd3e22c2

and one thing . i don't want to show profile pic separate . i want merge into one pic . so people can upload in FB .

Comment: What about it is not working? Yes, you aren't doing anything to output the image. See this thread for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961097/displaying-an-image-created-with-imagecreatefromstring

Comment: i fixed it . now can you tell me how to how to save that image in server and call it . and separate the script . i want call the final image like <img src=path to .php or .jpg >

Comment: That's a new question. SO frowns on asking new questions in the comments. Create a new question with this. Truthfully, I'm not even sure what the best way is to pass this large array of image URLs to a separate script.