# unable to convert image data into an actual image to display on html form

Tags: php, base64, signature

I am trying to display E-signature on a Form which is stored in database as type Blob, So far I am able to show the data but unable to convert it into an image, any help will be appreciated

Here is the code which I have got so far

```
`<?php
include('config.php');


// Prepare the SQL statement to select the signature data
$sql = "SELECT signatureData FROM details WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

// Bind the ID parameter to the prepared statement
$id = 104; // Replace with the ID of the signature data to retrieve
$stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

// Execute the prepared statement
$stmt->execute();

// Fetch the result and return the base64-encoded signature data
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($result) {
    $signatureData = $result['signatureData'];
    $imageData = base64_decode($signatureData);
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($imageData);
  
  
    // Output the signature data as an image
    echo $image;
  } else {
    echo "No signature data found for ID $id";
  }
  ?>`
```

Comment: what is signatureData looks like? is it an URL, binary blob, or base64-encoded? maybe you can give an example of first 20 characters if it is not gibberish

Comment: Try to see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961097/displaying-an-image-created-with-imagecreatefromstring) solves your problem

Comment: It is gibbersish...like this

Comment: Pippo! if I use this example then it gives this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromstring()

Answer (score 0):

Base 64 encoded image streams can be placed directly into the src attribute of an image tag using data URI scheme.

```
<img src=“<?php echo “data:image/png;base64,” . $signatureData ?> />
```

Inspect the string in your database to see if it already begins with “base64,” as you do not want to repeat this.

Comment: Ok so I am able to get the image but it is not showing if I am making my self understand. Like when it tells you its an image but it doesn't show the image.

Comment: This is the code so far and I am storing it as text in database
<?php
include('config.php');
$sql = "SELECT signature FROM details WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$id = "116"; // Replace with the ID of the signature data to retrieve
$stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($result) {
$signatureData = $result['signature'];
$imageData = base64_decode($signatureData);
$img = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($imageData) . '">';
echo $img;} else {echo "No signature data found for ID $id";} ?>